# Убрать отступы у Balloon

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Использую **JavaScript API 2.1**.
Создал свою разметку для **Balloon** и показываю его как панель внизу карты при клике на **Placemark**. Кастомная разметка задается через balloonContentLayout:

```
balloonContentLayoutClass = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
"<div class='flex_h'>" +
    "<div class='flex_v'>" +
        "<div class='title'>{{properties.balloonContentBody}}</div>" +
        "<div class='subtitle'>{{properties.balloonContent}}</div>" +
    "</div>" +
    "<button class='button' id='{{properties.placeId}}' onclick='locationSelected(this.id)'>" +
        "<span>&#8853;</span>" +
    "</button>" +
"</div>"
);

new ymaps.Placemark([lat, lng], {
    ...
}, {
    ...
    balloonContentLayout: balloonContentLayoutClass,
    preset: 'islands#icon',
    iconColor: '#F1973F',
    hasBalloon: true
})
```

Разметка имеет две части (по горизонтали), которые полностью заполнены разными цветами. Но, к сожалению, **Balloon** показывается с белыми отступами, что не соответствует моему дизайну.

1. Как убрать отступы у Balloon?
2. Можно ли это сделать в css?

Comment: Если предоставите код, то ответить будет проще. Пока методом догадок, предположу что вы задаёте balloonContentLayout или balloonContent. Если же вы хотите полностью поменять панель балун, то нужно реализовывать balloonPanelLayout.

Comment: у балунов и стили есть и кастомные шаблоны, можно и переопределить стили через css.

Comment: А как это сделать в css? Какой class у Balloon?

Comment: Добавил код разметки

Answer (score 1):

В общем, на данный момент такой возможности нет. Написал в службу поддержки Yandex - ответили, что можно менять только контент балуна, но не панель. Хотя, сказали что передали мое предложение менеджеру и разработчикам сервиса.

Буду следить за обновлениями.